# Losing points even after answer is accepted

Tags: support

[image]

my points should be 95 on the right hand side but shows only 50

please let me know if the site/moderators use bots for control

Comment: The area on the right side in your screenshot appears to show only 'recent' (for some definition of 'recent') reputation changes. If you look at the [reputation tab](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/197451/js-bibra?tab=reputation) (either by clicking on "view more" or by going to the tab directly) and click on the corresponding day, you'll see all relevant reputation changes. For yesterday I see +95 for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554008/35864.

Comment: Case in point: At this very moment the reputation area in the right side of your screenshot only shows +10 for the answer Latex: Align two tables side by side on top

Comment: @moewe Looks like the answer to me: I think 'recent' is 'most recent X events'

Answer (score 3):

The reputation area of the *Summary* tab on the *Activity* page as seen on the right in your screenshot appears to show only 'recent' reputation changes (for some definition of 'recent').

If you look at the [reputation tab](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/197451/js-bibra?tab=reputation) (either by clicking on "view more" or by going to the tab directly) and click on the corresponding day, you'll see all relevant reputation changes.

For yesterday I see +95 for your answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554008/35864 to [Latex: Align two tables side by side on top](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/554007/35864), so everything seems to be in order.