# Losing points again

Tags: support

[image]

see the last question on the right which has been accepted and upvoted but the points shown are only 15 it should be 25 -- why does this happen?

Comment: See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8622/35864: Don't worry about the summary. You can check your full reputation changes in detail at https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/197451/js-bibra?tab=reputation. If there are other reputation changes between an upvote to one of your answers and it being accepted, only one of the two events may end up in the summary. But rest assured both will be counted in the reputation tab (possibly unless you hit the reputation limit for the day).

Answer (score 7):

This has been explained multiple times: the 'summary' of 'recent' events simply cuts off at an arbitrary number of events. So the accepted and upvoted points can be split, one appearing and one not. Your full reputation summary shows the values.